Поиск параметров распределения
Нужна консультация специалиста по матстатистике.
Имеем набор случайных/псевдослучайных значений (вектор, массив), ожидается, что они имеют распределение вида AxD, где D < 0, и в диапазоне от m до M (от 0 до ∞ нельзя — интеграл расходится...). Задача - найти эти параметры (D, m, M).
Пробовал оценивать по оценке среднего значения x (сравнивая с теоретическим, полученным интегрированием), при этом в качестве оценки m и M брал просто минимальное и максимальное значения из набора. Показалось было :), что получается что-то похожее на правду, но для надежности сгенерировал несколько собственных тестовых наборов для разных D - получилось очень большое расхождение с правдой (типа, для -1 получаю -0.9, для -3 — -2.2).
Поискал в Интернете, напал на метод максимального правдоподобия, но что-то не пойму, оно ли это или нет, + как именно его применить к данной задаче.
Как вариант, подумал было для разных D поискать значение χ² и брать то D, для которого оно минимально, но пока не реализовал, так как с одной стороны, минимизация такой сложной функции — еще та проблема, а с другой — надо же разбить весь диапазон на несколько участков — а на сколько именно? как именно выбрать количество степеней свободы?
Словом, был бы признателен матстатистикам за советы...

Это наверное в специализированном сообществе лучше спрашивать. Но придётся на английском https://stats.stackexchange.com/

"метод максимального правдоподобия" - это оно.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Мне не понравилось то, что если я правильно понял, то можно взять логарифмическую функцию правдоподобия, но это будет сумма D*log(x_i), т.е. фактически линейная функция от D, которая никакого максимума не имеет. Это и заставило думать, что тут что-то не так. Или я совсем неверно понял, как строится функция правдоподобия? А как? :)

Сперва от распределения перейдите к плотности вероятности и уже к плотности примените ММП.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Так это же и есть плотность вероятности? 8-/

О, недопонял. У вас  параметры связаны условием что интеграл единичный. Уменьшать D не получится. Сделайте его вычислимым: D = D(A, m, M) и ищите минимум по A, m, M.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Я когда нагенерировал тестовые распределения, то m и M оказывались очень близки к минимальному и максимальному значению в сгенерированном наборе. Т.е. тут "размаха" никакого не будет. Не получится ли это какая-нибудь плохо определенная задача? Почему все спрашиваю, а не "взять и попробовать" — у меня электричество сейчас, спасибо тем, кто свято верит в "тебя излупят плетками и ты залюбишь меня как миленькая", очень большой дефицит, 3 часа из 9, так что мне надо максимально решать теоретически, на бумажке... Прям как в студенческие времена с большими ЭВМ :)

Связь между m и M есть. При фиксированных A, D их можно двигать не влияя на правдоподобие. Я подумаю над задаче плотнее завтра. Сегодня времени не много.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Тогда еще для размышления - а если m и M точно известны и фиксированы? Для тестовых сгенерированных мною наборов это ведь именно так. Update - забавно. При этом я получаю правильные (ну, по второму знаку так точно) результаты даже методом среднего значения...  Не думал, что так сильно зависит от границ. А как тогда быть в общем случае?...

Вы дали ответ на вопрос в вопросе, используйте метод правдоподобия.
Метод максимального правдоподобия или метод наибольшего правдоподобия в математической статистике — это метод оценивания неизвестного параметра путём максимизации функции правдоподобия. Основан на предположении о том, что вся информация о статистической выборке содержится в функции правдоподобия.
Лучше всего максимизировать логарифм правдоподобия. Вам можно реализовать это с помощью метода градиентного спуска.

См. вот эти выкладки. Это я расписывал функции для расчета и градиенты. И приравнял к нулю :) — и получается ерунда? Где я ошибся в выкладках? Но у меня получается ерунда, что M == 0...

Вы не должны игнорировать границы, вероятность любой точки данных за пределами [m, M] должна быть равна нулю.

А также в качестве примера если, у нас есть массив случайных чисел 1, 2, 3. То максимальное правдоподобие получается при m = 1, M = 3, D = 0,52 даст вам A = 0,7

И как тогда считать? Я пробовал набросать с использованием ALGLIB минимизацию, вобщем, просто вылетает куда-то в NaN. Разбираться некогда, у меня тут проблемы... так что вернусь к задаче где-то через неделю...
